# How to style specific cells in CellTable depending the value of that cell (GWT)?

Tags: gwt

Ok, i have a `CellTable` that has 3 columns and 2 rows. I want the text in SOME specific cells (not all cell) in the table to be BOLD.

Please look at this code:

```
ListDataProvider<List<String>> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<List<String>>();
dataProvider.addDataDisplay(table);
List<List<String>> list = dataProvider.getList();
List<String> sublist1= Arrays.asList("223","546","698");
List<String> sublist2= Arrays.asList("123","876","898");
List<String> sublist2= Arrays.asList("123","896","438");
IndexedColumn column1=new IndexedColumn(0);
table.addColumn(column1, "Col1");
IndexedColumn column2=new IndexedColumn(1);
table.addColumn(column2, "Col2");
IndexedColumn column3=new IndexedColumn(2);
table.addColumn(column3, "Col3");
```

Now, I want the Cell that is the intersect of row2 & col3 (ie "898") to be BOLD, so if i do like this

```
column3.setCellStyleNames(getView().getRes().css().myBoldColor());
```

Then it will make the whole column BOLD.

So, i think properly we need to loop over each cell in column3 & set the style accordingly, so that we can have the result like this:

```
Col1 - Col2 - Col3
223 - 546 - 698
123 - 876 - 898
123 - 896 - 438
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it be extending `AbstractCell` also.

Read here about [Implementing the render() Method](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomCells.html#cell-render).

*Sample code:*

```
static class BoldCell extends AbstractCell<String> {

    /**
     * The HTML templates used to render the cell.
     */
    interface Templates extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
        @SafeHtmlTemplates.Template("<div style=\"{0}\">{1}</div>")
        SafeHtml cell(SafeStyles styles, SafeHtml value);
    }

    /**
     * Create a singleton instance of the templates used to render the cell.
     */
    private static Templates templates = GWT.create(Templates.class);

    @Override
    public void render(Context context, String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        /*
         * Always do a null check on the value. Cell widgets can pass null to cells if the
         * underlying data contains a null, or if the data arrives out of order.
         */
        if (value == null) {
            return;
        }

        // If the value comes from the user, we escape it to avoid XSS attacks.
        SafeHtml safeValue = SafeHtmlUtils.fromString(value);

        // Use the template to create the Cell's html.
        FontWeight weight = FontWeight.NORMAL;
        if (safeValue.asString().equals("898")) {
            weight = FontWeight.BOLD;
        }
        SafeStyles styles = SafeStylesUtils.forFontWeight(weight);
        SafeHtml rendered = templates.cell(styles, safeValue);
        sb.append(rendered);
    }
}
```

---

In above code you can try it with row no also (Bold value for 0th column of 3rd row)

```
        ...
        FontWeight weight = FontWeight.NORMAL;
        if (context.getIndex()==2) {
            weight = FontWeight.BOLD;
        }
        ...
```

---

```
    Cell<String> cell = new BoldCell();

    Column<Contact, String> nameColumn = new Column<Contact, String>(cell) {
        @Override
        public String getValue(Contact object) {
            return object.name;
        }
    };
    table.addColumn(nameColumn, "Name");
```

Comment: Let me know if you want complete code, if it's not clear to you.

Comment: Thank You Very Very Much Braj, I did. The key point is that we can get row index via context param of getCellStyleNames in IndexedColumn. I didn't know how to get the row index in IndexedColumn before.

Anyway, I did a little different from yours but the logic is the same & I fixed, so easy, thank you very very much.

Answer (score 1):

Override getCellStyleNames() for a column:

```
Column<Document, Date> dueColumn = new Column<Document, Date>(new DateCell(DateTimeFormat.getFormat(PredefinedFormat.MONTH_ABBR_DAY))) {

    @Override
    public Date getValue(Document document) {
        return document.getDueDate();
    }

    @Override
    public String getCellStyleNames(Context context, Document document) {

    if (document.getDueDate().getTime() < new Date().getTime()) {
        return "boldStyle";
    }
};
```

Comment: You have your object. You can use any property of this object when deciding which style to apply to this particular cell. It does not have to be the property used in this column. For example, you can compare both document.getDueDate() and document.getStartDate().

Comment: the problem is that I can only style the cell based on its position which is the intersection between cell and column, yo can see my new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602090/how-to-style-the-cell-that-is-the-intersection-of-row-and-column-in-celltable-g

Comment: The solution that I provided is specifically for *the intersection between row and column*. There is a different solution for rows, and another solution for columns. This solution is for individual cells.