# How to style the cell that is the intersection of row and column in celltable (GWT)?

Tags: gwt

Ok, i have a `CellTable` that has 3 columns and 2 rows. I want the text in SOME specific cells (not all cell) in the table to be BOLD.

Please look at this code:

```
ListDataProvider<List<String>> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<List<String>>();
dataProvider.addDataDisplay(table);
List<List<String>> list = dataProvider.getList();
List<String> sublist1= Arrays.asList("223","546","698");
List<String> sublist2= Arrays.asList("123","876","898");
List<String> sublist2= Arrays.asList("123","896","438");
IndexedColumn column1=new IndexedColumn(0);
table.addColumn(column1, "Col1");
IndexedColumn column2=new IndexedColumn(1);
table.addColumn(column2, "Col2");
IndexedColumn column3=new IndexedColumn(2);
table.addColumn(column3, "Col3");
```

I tried, it almost done, BUT...

Suppose I want to style the cell that is the intersection of the following Row Index and Column Index: (Note: index start from 0, so column2 got index=1)

```
Row - Col
0   -  1
0   -  2
1   -  1
1   -  2
2   -  2
```

Clearly, I just want to style 5 cells only.

So i did like you said:

in css file:

```
.boldRow .boldColumn { font-weight: bold; }
```

Then in the java file

```
column2.setCellStyleNames(getView().getRes().css().boldColumn());
column3.setCellStyleNames(getView().getRes().css().boldColumn());

table.setRowStyles(new RowStyles<List<String>>() {
   @Override
   public String getStyleNames(List<String> row, int rowIndex) {


      if(rowIndex==0 || rowIndex==1 || rowIndex==2){
          return getView().getRes().css().boldRow();
      }
      return null;
   }

});
```

ANd here is the result:

```
Col1 - Col2 - Col3
223 - 546 - 698
123 - 876 - 898
123 - 896 - 438
```

Clearly, i don't want this cell (row index =2 & columm index=3) bold. But the result include it.

So how to fix it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361648/dynamic-styles-for-gwt-celltable-cells looks like the way to do it is to override  getCellStyleNames.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style specific cells in CellTable depending the value of that cell (GWT)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598596/how-to-style-specific-cells-in-celltable-depending-the-value-of-that-cell-gwt)

Comment: @Andrei, that question is for styling based on the value of the cell, this question is styling based on the intersection row col, not based on the value, so they are different

Comment: A cell *is* the intersection of a column and a row. The answer is exactly the same. In my answer to your previous question, context.getIndex() gives you a row number.

Comment: but i want to format based on the position of the cell, not based on the value of the cell as "Thomas Broyer" suggested https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/KEZo7pucsmc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find my post her [How to style specific cells in CellTable depending the value of that cell (GWT)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598596/how-to-style-specific-cells-in-celltable-depending-the-value-of-that-cell-gwt/22615728#22615728).

This will solve your problem.

Use below code in `AbstractCell`

```
        ...
        FontWeight weight = FontWeight.BOLD;
        if (context.getColumn()==0 || (context.getIndex()==1 && context.getColumn()==2)) {
            weight = FontWeight.NORMAL;
        }
        ...
```