# styling CellTable Row depending on it's value

Tags: css, gwt

I need to change the color of the row in `CellTble` depending on its value, I'm setting the style by  (`cellTable.css`) file using `Interface CellTable.Style` .

I tried the code :

```
AttendanceTable.setRowStyles(new RowStyles<AttendanceRecord>(){

            @Override
            public String getStyleNames(AttendanceRecord row, int rowIndex) {

                if(row.getName().equals("-"))
                    return"blueText";
                else
                    return"normalText";
            }

        });
```

and both (`blueText` , `normalText`)are defined in my `project.css` file but it don't see them.

any suggestions? ... thanks in advance.

my `cellTable.css` file is as follow:

```
/**  
 * table styles     
*/

.cellTableCell {
border:0px;
border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
height: 37px;
color:#7f7f7f;
font-size: 12px;
font-family: sans-serif;
padding-left: 10px;
}

.cellTableHeader {
color: #FFFFFF;
border:0px;
border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
border-bottom: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
background-color: #6AA0BF;
text-align: center;
font-size:11px;
text-shadow: none;
overflow: hidden;
height: 50px;
font-family: sans-serif;
}
.cellTableEvenRow {
background: #C8CED6;
text-align: center;
}

.cellTableOddRow {
background: #DFE7F2;
text-align: center;
}

.cellTableHoveredRow {
background: #D0D8E8 ;
text-align: center;
}
.cellTableSelectedRow {
background: #ea9706;
text-align: center;

}
.cellTableSelectedRowCell {
    color: white ;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style the cell that is the intersection of row and column in celltable (GWT)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602090/how-to-style-the-cell-that-is-the-intersection-of-row-and-column-in-celltable-g)

Comment: See one more [duplicate post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598596/how-to-style-specific-cells-in-celltable-depending-the-value-of-that-cell-gwt/22615728#22615728)

Comment: What do the `blueTexte` and `normalText` look like? Could be a conflict with `cellTableCell`'s `color: #7f7f7f;`.

Comment: user3218114 , thanks for your comment.. yes it was very useful ,, regards

Comment: Thomas Boyer .. it won't see it .. i solved my problem thank you .. Regards .